# Exportar una tabla en html a un archivo excel usando openpyxl en una función flask

Tags: flask

quiero exportar una tabla que tengo en un html a un archivo excel desde flask.

En la plantilla html tengo este código:

```
<main>
    <div class="row g-0 w-100 mt-4">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form action="{{url_for('exportar_excel')}}" method="POST">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sortable" id="parts-table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="date-head">Fecha</th>
                            <th scope="col">Dedicación</th>
                            <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="type-head">Tipo de tarea</th>
                            <th scope="col">Estado de tarea</th>
                            <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="employee-head" scope="col">Técnico</th>
                            <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="customer-head" scope="col">Cliente</th>
                            <th id="work-head" scope="col">Tarea</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                            {% if g.employee %}
                            <th id="edit-btn-head" scope="col">Ver/Editar</th>
                            {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            {%for pruebas in prueba%}
                            {% for valor in pruebas %}
                                <tr>

                                    <td id="line_date" scope="row" style="width: 100px">{{ valor.fecha }}</td>
                                    <td id="line_duration" >{{ (valor.dedicacion|string)[:-3] }}</td>
                                    <td id="line_work-type" style="width: 140px">{{ valor.tipo_tarea}}</td>
                                    <td id="line_status"  style="width: 140px">{{ valor.estado_tarea}}</td>
                                    <td id="line_employee">{{ valor.tecnico}}</td>
                                    <td id="line_party" >{{ valor.cliente}}</td>
                                    <td id="line_work" >{{ valor.tarea }}</td>
                                    <td id="line_description">{{ valor.descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td id="line_internal-description" style="display:none;">{{ valor.editor_ver }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {%endfor%}
                            {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="datos" value="{{ datos_tabla }}">
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Exportar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Para poder recoger los datos de la tabla he creado:

Que ahora llamaré desde la función de flask.

En flask he hecho lo siguiente:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

@app.route('/exportar_excel', methods=['POST'])
@tryton.transaction()
def exportar_excel():
    datos_tabla = request.form.get('datos')
    print(datos_tabla)
    # creamos hoja en excel para guardar la tabla
    libro_excel = Workbook()
    hoja = libro_excel.active

    #para guardar cada una de las líneas
    for fila in datos_tabla:
        hoja.append(fila)

    # creamos la ruta de descargas
    archivo_excel = 'tabla_prueba.xls'
    ruta_descarga = '/home/osboxes/Documentos/'+archivo_excel
    libro_excel.save(ruta_descarga)
    return send_file(ruta_descarga, as_attachment=True)
```

Se supone que aquí recogería los datos al llamar al name="datos"

datos_tabla = request.form.get('datos')

Pero cuando ejecuto la app y le doy al botón de exportar resulta que me generá el archivo excel, pero vacio, he comprobado haber que datos me pasa por la variable datos_tabla, y resulta que es None.

Estoy revisando el código y no veo nada mal